# Scraping data using php curl and proxies

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, proxy

I am using the below script for scraping data, when I access the php page, it only works with few websites like Google, for rest of them, it will be just a blank page. Is there an issue with the code? and how to debug it?

```
<?php

$request = curl_init("https://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer 31d15a'
));

$response = curl_exec($request);
echo $response;
curl_close($request);
```

[image]

Comment: there are a lot more settings that you often need to set when making curl requests - some websites require certain things are present in the request ( too broad to specify ) - to debug use `curl_info`

Comment: Where is the "proxies" part?

Comment: calling that using API "'Authorization: Bearer 31d15a'"

Answer (score 0):

There are more options to set, but following may be sufficient for your task.

```
//Initialise Curl
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url to be used
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//follow HTTP 3xx redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//automatically update the referer header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

//accept the responce after the execution
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//don't verify the peer's SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//set the browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

//executes given cURL session.
$html = curl_exec($ch);

//disable libxml errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

//closes Curl session, & frees up the associated memory
curl_close($ch);
```